# Disabled Mage Core

Tags: magento-1.9

I accidently disabled mage core while attempting to turn off modules one at a time to help fix a duplication issue, and now my control interface won't work. I have tried a system restore, and doing an SQL query that i found online

UPDATE core_config_data SET value=0 WHERE path='advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_Core';

This did not work.  Any other suggestions to help me get up and running again?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that you cannot actually disable modules in "System > Configuration > Advanced". The "Disable Module Output" settings only hide all blocks that belong to these modules, everything else is still executed, including all layout changes.

That being said, if you disabled module output for `Mage_Core`, the SQL query that you used is correct to revert this setting. But additionally you have to clean the cache, because configuration is cached and a direct change in the database does not trigger cache invalidation.

If you use the default file based cache, simply delete all directories below `var/cache`.